# get or set request variable in pre-request script in Hoppscotch

Tags: hoppscotch

In Hoppscotch v2024.3.0 how can I get or set the newly introduced request variables from a pre-request script?

I tried using `pw.env.get("my_reqest_variable")` but it returns `undefined`.